# How to set up port forwarding from MAC host to Vagrant Linux VM to Docker containers with Kubernetes?

Tags: virtualbox, docker, vagrant

I am utilizing [this guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md) on 1 VM managed by Vagrant

I can access the containers that I start locally inside the VM just fine, but I can't seem to access them from the host machine. I have kubernetes running inside of a VM, but it isn't port fowarding out to the the host machine. I tried, the following: [How to set up port forwarding from Windows host to Vagrant Linux VM to Docker containers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/686076/) thanks to @analytik.  I attempted the step, but it didn't seem to bear fruit. I didn't do any ssh tunneling as I am trying to get the port forwarding to work automatically.

I do have it setup for NAT and Host-Only networking. The interesting thing, even before I setup a kubernetes pod, the kubernetes master api is available inside of the VM at localhost:8080 as so:

```
vagrant@local:/usr/local/bin$ curl localhost:8080 { "paths": [ "/api", "/api/v1", "/healthz", "/healthz/ping", "/logs/", "/metrics", "/resetMetrics", "/swagger-ui/", "/swaggerapi/", "/ui/", "/version" ] }
```

But when I try to access that from the Mac I can't seem to reach it:

```
curl localhost:8080 curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

So it is getting something, but not sure what is happening. I do have my Adapter 1 set to Nat with my various port forwarding rules, and my Adapter 2 set to Host-only Adapter.

Any thoughts? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: So for my services that I expose, I am able to connect utilizing type: NodePort and a setting a nodePort.  I am still unsure how to connect to the kuernetes master API, so any other thoughts would be really helpful.  Thanks again!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem. I want to use the Kubernetes API from the outside. I saw the description of using NodePort for your own services in the docs on "Publishing a Service," but since the Kubernetes service itself isn't defined by us, how do we give it the NodePort type? Where is that defined?